# Marginal probability densities

Tags: probability-distributions

I am trying to work on the following problem, and can't seem to quite figure out how to work out the marginal probability density functions:

Given

$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
      k & 0 \leq x \leq 2\,,\quad 0 \leq y \leq 1\,,\quad 2y \leq x \\[1mm]
      0 & \mbox{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
$

I am asked to find $k$ so that $f(x,y)$ is a probability density function. I worked it out to $k=1$, but then I'm asked to find the marginal probability densities for $x$ and $y$ and I'm hitting a bit of a roadblock.

In order to find the x marginal, I integrate against $y$:

$f_x = \int_{o}^{1}dy = \dots = 1$

That's interesting - the marginal probability of $x$ is 1? Well, maybe. Let's move on.

In order to find the y marginal, I integrate against $x$:

$f_y = \int_{o}^{2}dx = \dots = 2$

Now *clearly* this is wrong. I am 99% sure that my calculation of $k$ is correct, and that the issue is that my integration limits are borked.

If someone could explain how to find the marginal here, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: you forgot the third condition $2y<x$ and its impact on the marginal integrals' bounds.

$$f_X(x) ~=~ \int_0^{\min\{x/2,1\}}\mathbf 1_{0\leq x\leq 2}\operatorname d y~=~\frac x 2\cdotp\mathbf 1_{0\leq x\leq 2}$$

Can you do the other?

Comment: Thanks - that's what I figured. I was struggling to figure out how to apply that condition. I think I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: So, I would integrate from $2y$ to $2$, and get $2(1-y)$? for the y-marginal?

Comment: @ConfusedMathStudent Yes, $\int_{2y}^2\operatorname d x=2-2y$   But don't forget to note where the support lies.  $0\leq y\leq 1$

Comment: Thanks - I'll read up on supports more closely!